# Magento 1.9.3.9 MySQL Database error

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, mysql-indexes

I'm getting some error from Magento MySQL database. I tried to fix it from "Magento Database Repair Tool" , unfortunately it shows "reference DB doesn't seem to be a valid Magento database". Please tell me, how can I fix it.

Please Help.

Comment: Show please your code and code error

Comment: are you trying to make an import?

Comment: yes, i was uploading some product for test.

Comment: sir, how can i fix it.? please help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to occur when you're importing a table definition that had been created with MyISAM but later was switched to InnoDB; the resulting ROW_FORMAT options appear to be invalid.

If you're trying to import an exported database and encounter this problem, you can simply search and replace `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` with nothing.

I used the following to do so really quickly:

```
sed -ie 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' backup.sql
```

> Run this command in directory with file.sql

Removing `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` option from CREATE TABLE DDL will fix the issue. So let’s try possible solutions.

## 1

```
sed -i 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' magento-db-dump.sql
```

This didn’t work for me in MacOSx which resulted in the following error:

> sed: 1: “magento-db-dump.sql”: invalid command code m

## 2

```
sed -i '' 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' magento-db-dump.sql
```

And even this resulted as:

> sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

## 3 But this one worked for me in MacOSx

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i '' 's/ROW_FORMAT=FIXED//g' magento-db-dump.sql
```

Comment: if I helped you, choose my answer as correct